# "Your valentine" vs "my valentine"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, pronouns

I am going to send a gift to a far away lady I care a great deal about.I want to write her a card just to tell her I will always be there for her when she needs me, so to speak (not in any sexual sense though).

Bear in mind this is not an affair or a date, we have not met each other for the last 28 years and are separated physically by seven thousands miles (we have been communicating for some years now though after she has no SO in her life due to an unfortunate sudden accident followed by chronic illness).

I want to write one sentence.

Should I say: "I will always be your Valentine" or "you will always be my Valentine"?

English being my second language I really do not have a feel for the difference, so to speak. OR should I use a different word other than Valentine.

Comment: To avoid sounding romantic, you could just say: "A Valentine for you... from far away," or "Sending you hugs on Valentine's Day". (Something that avoids "my" and "your".)

Comment: If you want her to understand that you have singled her out especially > as a sweetheart: "will you be my valentine?" or "I will always be your Valentine" or "**you will always be my  Valentine"**...are correct forms, but with romantic connotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend sending a valentine card in such a situation at all - Valentine cards carry connotations of sexual desire (or romantic intent, depending on how sensitive you are) intended to be sent anonymously to the recipient, despite the greetings cards companies trying to persuade people otherwise. It seems this would be inappropriate in these circumstances. Send a 'thinking of you' card if you must send something, or wait for her birthday or some other important anniversary.

Note that an expression such as 'you will always be my Valentine' specifically means 'you will always be my love' or even 'lover'.

Comment: I think that many Valentine cards are sent just for fun, and are treated as such. But you're right that it's often playing with fire.

Comment: Children exchange valentines for fun, for adults it's likely to be more indicative of romantic feelings.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm aware of that, as indeed I know a mum who sends her son one, very weird indeed - the purpose of valentine's day has been subverted by card companies

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think the whole modern valentine thing is weird, its been subverted, but then I guess the original purpose of the Maypole has also been buried, since children indulge in it as a piece of pretty pastoral history, which it certainly wasn't! I would certainly attribute receipt of a valentine as its original meaning - and that's certainly what was meant when I used to get them, with the sender usually revealing themselves within a month or so.

Comment: The only maypole in Oldham (Failsworth Pole) burnt down decades ago, and was replaced by a free-standing 20' brick clock-tower. A sign of the times.